# Hibernate ORM with Apache Netbeans 12 Java Maven Application

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, netbeans, orm

I have been trying for 3 days to integrate Hibernate with my Java Swing application (Maven). I haven't been able to add the Hibernate plugin because the installation is always unsuccessful. I'm using SQLite as my database and using Linux as my operating system. Any ideas/suggestions?

[Unsuccessful installation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8XWW.png)

Comment: The error is a netbeans error, so I added that to the question.

Comment: You're right, thank you. @JFabianMeier